# Get Tasks That Fall Between Date Range OR Are Outside of Date Range

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

This is going to be a complicated matter to explain - but I'll try my best.
Below I have a method to grab all tasks (from a specific team) that are assigned to user within a date range...

Right now, it's working as it should (partially):

- Get Tasks from current team
- that are assigned to the auth'd user

Need tasks where...

- task start date falls within date range
- task due date falls within date range

But I also need tasks that the **start date** *could be* **BEFORE** date range AND/OR **due date** *could be* **AFTER** date range.

**This works great. However, it's also grabbing tasks from other teams. For example, if I switch to team 2. Tasks for Team 1 that are *assigned* to user will appear as well (when they shouldn't be).**

So I'm assuming it has something to do with my `where` clauses. It's a complicated beast. Hoping someone can help.

Method:

```
$tasks = Team::currentTeam()
    ->tasks()
    ->assignedToUser()
    ->where([
        ['status', '!=', 'completed'],
        ['due_date', '<=', $start_date],
        ['start_date', '<>', $start_date],
        ['start_date', '<', $end_date],
    ])
    ->orWhere([
        ['due_date', '>', $start_date]
    ])
->get();
```

Current Team Scope:

```
public function scopeCurrentTeam($query)
{
    $current_team = Auth::user()->current_team_id;
    return $query->find($current_team);
}
```

Assigned to user scope:

```
public function scopeAssignedToUser($query)
{
    return $query->with('user', 'comments')->whereHas('user', function($query) {
        $query->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id);
    })->orHas('user', '=', 0);
}
```

Comment: can we see the `scopeTasks`

Comment: it's a relationship... `return $this->hasMany(Task::class);`

Comment: `assignedToUser` doesn't care about that hasMany relationship. Can you show me how a task is related to a user?

Comment: It's a pivot table... `return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);` same `return `$this->belongsToMany(Task::class);` on Users table.

Comment: so `tasks_users` is the table then? I think we can do this a bit different way, still using Eloquent, though.

Comment: `task_user` is the table. I've been trying to wrap my head around this all day. Hopefully you can point me in the right direction. It's a complex query.

Comment: Can you try something like this: `Team::currentTeam()->with('tasks')->whereHas('user', function($query){ return $query->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id) })`

Comment: To replace `$tasks` variable - or a scope?

Comment: and wouldn't this look for relationship between team and user? i.e. where has user of team, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out - put my thinking cap on, wrote out all the possible scenarios for the query and got it to work.

First I had to wrap my massive list of `wheres` in a `->where(function()..` so my where classes (like I had before), didn't conflict with my relationship (`tasks()`) and the `assignedToUser()` scope.

**Maybe there's a cleaner way to perform this? It's f--kin' ugly...I got a "checkmark" for whoever can ;) I'm likely going to create a scope for that long where and get it out of my controller.**

```
$tasks = Team::currentTeam()
    ->tasks()
    ->assignedToUser()
    ->where(function ($query) use ($start_date, $end_date) {
        $query->where([
            // Task falls on or between date range
            ['start_date', '>=', $start_date],
            ['start_date', '<=', $end_date],
            ['due_date', '>=', $start_date],
            ['due_date', '<=', $end_date]
        ])                
        ->orWhere([
            // Task is overdue from previous week
            ['start_date', '<', $start_date],
            ['due_date', '<', $start_date],
            ['status', '!=', 'completed']
        ])                
        ->orWhere([
            // Task start before date range
            // and due date is past end of date range
            ['start_date', '<', $start_date],
            ['due_date', '>', $end_date]
        ])
        ->orWhere([
            // Task start within date range, 
            // but due date is past end of date range
            ['start_date', '>=', $start_date],
            ['start_date', '<=', $end_date],
            ['due_date', '>', $end_date]
        ])
        ->orWhere([
            // Task due date within date range, 
            // but start date is before start of date range
            ['due_date', '>=', $start_date],
            ['due_date', '<=', $end_date],
            ['start_date', '<', $start_date]
        ]);
    })            
->get();
```